# Calculate the estimated time of arrival (ETA) of the clouds by using Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I'm working in a project for a weather station but I got stuck in something which is the estimated time of arrival (ETA) so, I would like to also apply a method that estimates the arrival time of the clouds to a certain spot, for example, I will have a solar station and then there will be clouds but before they reach the solar station I want to calculate the estimated time of arrival to the station? It shouldn't be that accurate though.

Here is the data that I'm having currently.

From spot A to spot B >> 1km

Wind speed changes between >> 1.5 - 3.6 m/s

Here is the code for weather forecasting:

```
import pyowm
import os
from datetime import datetime
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
APIKEY=''
OpenWMap=pyowm.OWM(APIKEY)
Weather=OpenWMap.weather_at_place('Location')
Data=Weather.get_weather()
Weatherforecast = OpenWMap.three_hours_forecast('Location')

date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y | %I:%M:%S")

print ("-------------------------------------------------------------")
print ("Weather Status for - Location || {}".format(date_time))
print ("-------------------------------------------------------------")

temp = Data.get_temperature(unit='celsius')
print ("Average Temp. Currently ", temp['temp'] , '°C')
print ("Max Temp. Currently ", temp['temp_max'], '°C')
print ("Min Temp. Currently ", temp['temp_min'], '°C')


humidity = Data.get_humidity()
print ("Humidity : ",humidity, '%')


wind = Data.get_wind()
print ("Wind Speed : ",wind['speed'], 'm/s')
print ("Wind Direction in Deg : ",wind['deg'],'°')


cloud = Data.get_clouds()
print ("Cloud Coverage Percentage : ",cloud, '%')

weatherstatus = Data.get_status()
weatherstatusdetailed = Data.get_detailed_status()
print ("Weather status : ",weatherstatus)
print ("Weather status with details :",weatherstatusdetailed)

rain=Weatherforecast.will_have_rain()
sun=Weatherforecast.will_have_sun()
cloud=Weatherforecast.will_have_clouds() 

print("There will be rain :",rain)
print("There will be sun :",sun)
print("There will be clouds :",cloud)
```

I'm also using camera pi with OpenCV library to mask the clouds,

Here is the part of the cloud coverage which will indicate when the ETA calculation must start so when the percentage of the cloud coverage is 50% or more it will start. CODE:

```
# determine the cloud coverage
    cloud_pixels   = np.count_nonzero(inverted == 255)
    total_pixels   = result.size
    cloud_coverage = cloud_pixels / total_pixels

    # create a mask of where the clouds are
    cloud_image_mask = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cloud_image_mask[mask] = inverted.flatten()

    print('Coverage is {:.3f}%'.format(cloud_coverage*100))
    print(datetime.now() - startTime)

    last_dot  = imagepath.rindex('.')
    save_path = imagepath[:last_dot] + '-mask' + imagepath[last_dot:]
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, cloud_image_mask)

    return(cloud_coverage)
```

And here is the code for the wind speed so it's changing every few minutes or hours and when it changes I want it to be applied. CODE:

```
wind = Data.get_wind()
print ("Wind Speed : ",wind['speed'], 'm/s')
print ("Wind Direction in Deg : ",wind['deg'],'°')
```

Here is the calculation math:

The simplified case is quite obvious:

- The distance d is 1000m
- the speed s is 3.6 to 1.5 m/s
- ETA is in d/s = 278 to 667 seconds

Comment: Just to clarify because there's a lot of information in there, you want to calculate how long it will take for a cloud to travel the distance of 1km at a rate of 1.5-3.6m/s. Correct?

Comment: @IsaacWP121 Exactly

Comment: Post updated. More info given

Comment: I dont know if this is what you're looking for hence the comment, but, if cloud coverage is >= 50% you can get the wind speed then do d/s to get the seconds. Upon a significant (up to you how significant) wind speed change (almost to act as a buffer to stop it from constantly spitting out small changes)  would you be able to recalculate d and get a new eta?

Comment: @IsaacWP121 Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my solution to your problem, simplified however.

```
while True:
    If cloud_coverage >= 0.5: # if the cloud coverage is 50% or greater
        eta = d/wind["speed"] # calculate the eta

    if abs(wind["speed"] - Data.get_wind()["speed"]) > variance_tolerance: 
    #if the absolute value of the difference between wind["speed"] and an updated wind speed 
    #is greater then the tolerance
        wind = Data.get_wind() #reassign the wind variable
        #recalculate d
        eta = d/wind["speed] #recalculate the eta
```

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot .... I have got this error:              NameError: name 'variance_tolerance' is not defined

Comment: I have also made some changes this way:                                
       `while True:
        if cloud_coverage >= 0.5: 
            eta = 1000/wind["speed"] 
        if abs(wind["speed"] - Data.get_wind()["speed"]) > 
variance_tolerance: 
            wind = Data.get_wind() #reassign the wind variable
        #recalculate d
            eta = 1000/wind["speed"] #recalculate the eta
            print('ETA = ', eta)`

Comment: @wrongpath the variance_tolerance variable is just a placeholder variable to dictate how big of a change it would take before the new eta is calculated

Comment: Also @wrongpath that code you changed (changing out d for 1000) defeats the purpose of the code I wrote. how do you calculate the distance between your location and the cloud? You want to assign d to that then when it says # recalculate d you use that same distance formula to recalculate d